# NoClassDefFoundError when running java file on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm on ubuntu 10.04

when I try to execute a java program in a directory I get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

I run the program with this command:

```
 java -cp . Cli
```

This should run right? I am in the same directory as the Cli.java file, as you can see from the ls command. I have tried setting the CLASSPATH variable, I believe things broke after this. I did delete the CLASSPATH export from my .bashrc

What can I try?

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/jahmm-0.6.1/src/be/ac/ulg/montefiore/run/jahmm/apps/cli# ls
AbnormalTerminationException.java  CreateActionHandler.java    KMeansActionHandler.java  Types.java
ActionHandler.java                 Garage.class                Operations.class          Vehicule.class
BWActionHandler.java               GenerateActionHandler.java  Operators.class           WrongArgumentsException.java
Car.class                          HelpActionHandler.java      PrintActionHandler.java
Cli.java                           IntegerOperators.class      RelatedObjs.java
CommandLineArguments.java          KLActionHandler.java        Test.class
```

Comment: you need to compile Cli.java first with javac to generate the class file, then use the command above.

Comment: In your directory listing, I don't see `Cli.class` - only `Cli.java`.  Did you compile it?

Comment: i tried compiling the program, but it generates errors. It's a package i downloaded, it obviously doesnt work. Will use something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in the same directory as the `Cli.java` file, but you're trying to *run* it, not *compile* it... you need to compile it first:

```
javac Cli.java
java -cp . Cli
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *[compile](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html)* that `Cli.java` into a `Cli.class`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first compile the Cli.java file.

```
javac Cli.java
```

to produce a `.class` file. It looks like you are trying to just run the Cli.java file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all of the above answers. I strongly urge you to use an IDE such as Eclipse, which you will find through your package manager. Then you can let Eclipse take care of compiling, among countless other things.

Comment: i have eclipse, but it's a stripped version i guess. When writing javacode there is no color coding?